# problem trying to install sitecore commerce experience 9.0.2

Tags: sitecore-commerce, xconnect, installation

I got the following error and search online looks like it's something to do with xconnect remoting? I have disabled the xconnect site and also the
Go to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fsni.sc\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceAnalytics\` and disable `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.config` to disable it by placing `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.config.Disabled` right?
but it still looks like its running agianst please help

> [--------------------------------------------------------------
> InstallModule : InstallModule
> --------------------------------------------------------------] Installing module:  Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core
> 11.2.83.zip                                                                                    http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore
> Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core 11.2.83.zip
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration :
> One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to
> the 'item:saved' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across online and found this solution

Solution:

There are two solutions for this problem.

Make sure the xConnect site works with SSL(https).
If xConnect site does not work, alternative solution to bypass the above error is to comment out the `item:saved` event.
To do so, perform the following:

Navigate to the web site path “`\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceAnalytics\Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config`”.
Open the file and find the following xml configuration section
Comment out the above section and Rerun the “Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1” to add commerce module again.

```
<event name=”item:saved”>
  <handler type=”Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client” method=”OnItemSaved”>

    <param type=”Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.DeploySegmentDefinitionProcessor, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client”>
      <param ref=”experienceAnalytics/client/logger” />
      <param type=”Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentStore, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core”>
      </param>
    </param>

  </handler>
</event>
```